# Error 500 not leaving a "xml" in "Failed Request Tracing Logs" (Azure)?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I have an app in Azure and I'm monitoring that every request is HTTP 200 (OK)

Yesterday I had many errors HTTP 500 and I went to **"Diagnose and solve problems > Failed Request Tracing Logs"** and for each of these errors there was a .xml with the detailed information.

Thanks to these logs I solved the problem in my app and deployed again. After this all the requests were HTTP 200.

But today something happend and I had 17 errors HTTP 500:
[image: error 500 in azure]

And then I went to **"Diagnose and solve problems > Failed Request Tracing Logs"** but there are no .xml for these errors.

I thought: maybe Azure is not logging anymore, so I provoked a 404 but the .xml appeared there, so...

Question:  Why I don't have 17 xml for these HTTP500 ?

Answer (score 0):

If I [turn on "**Failed Request Tracing**"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-enable-diagnostic-log), I can get the failed requests logs, please make sure you have enabled it.

***Failed Request Tracing***

[image]

**Failed requests logs**

[image]

Besides, the failed requests logs should be stored in `/LogFiles/W3SVC#########/` folder, you can go to that folder using [Kudu Console](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Kudu-console) and check if the logs are there.

[image]

Comment: It is already "ON" for my app. In fact the 404 I provoked created a .xml. That is why i'm asking: Why I don't have 17 xmls for these HTTP 500 ? is it possible that a HTTP 500 occurs without creating the xml?

Comment: Please try to deploy your app to another Azure app service and turn on Failed Request Tracing, and check if logs are generated for 500 error.